# Keep form data without removing in Swagger

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger to describe and document my ASP.Net web API. After running the API on browser, I can enter the input parameters and test my endpoint. But after closing the browser and running the API, I have to add all the input parameters again and again. My question is, Is there a way to keep previous input parameters without removing?

Comment: Use Postman instead :)

Comment: Finally, this is the answer so far...

Comment: Added as an answer, perhaps, it helps someone looking for the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, there is no direct way to save the data in Swagger. However, you can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to solve your issue. It helps end to end in API development, debugging, testing, and documentation.

Comment: Yes. This is the way I am doing now. Thanks for the answer.